# function that formats the time difference

Tags: php, function, time

I am trying to create a function that compares a date with the current time, and returns a nicely formatted string.
I have written some code in haste and it works, but I am trying to find a more efficient way of doing it. Here is my code:

```
    function _formatDate($dateStr)
    {
    $timestr = "";
    $t= time() - strtotime($dateStr);
    if($t < 60) {
        $timestr = "{$t} seconds ago";
    }
    elseif ($t <120) {
        $timestr = "about a minute ago";
    }
    elseif ($t < 3600) {
        $minute = floor($t/60);
        $timestr = "{$minute} minutes ago";
    }
    elseif ($t < 7200) {
        $timestr = " about an hour ago";
    }
    elseif ($t < 86400) {
        $hour = floor($t/3600);
        $timestr = "{$hour} hours ago";
    }
    elseif ($t < 172800) {
        $timestr = "a day ago";
    }
    elseif ($t < 2592000) {
        $day = floor($t/86400);
        $timestr = "{$day} days ago";
    }
    elseif ($t < 5184000){
        $timestr = "about a month ago";
    }
    else {
        $month = floor($t/2592000);
        $timestr = "{$month} months ago";
    }
    return $timestr;
}
```

Comment: i am trying to pass the date as an argument and to have it return automaticly formated ex: 22 minutes ago, or 3 days ago

Comment: So what's wrong with your code?  Seems to do what you're asking.  If this is for a webpage, outputting as date/time stamps and then using JS (and a library like TimeAgo) to update the values is probably beneficial.

Comment: i want to know if there is a more efficient way to do it, without so many if else statement.

Comment: Efficient is hard to define...  Less lines - certainly.  Easier to understand - questionable.  Requires less processing - unlikely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some code I use and it's never failed, just put the Unix timestamp in, if you use a second argument in the function that can be the "to" condition

```
echo timeDiffrence('1300392875');

function timeDiffrence($from, $to = null){
    $to = (($to === null) ? (time()) : ($to));
    $to = ((is_int($to)) ? ($to) : (strtotime($to)));
    $from = ((is_int($from)) ? ($from) : (strtotime($from)));
    $units = array
    (
    "y"   => 29030400, // seconds in a year   (12 months)
    "month"  => 2419200,  // seconds in a month  (4 weeks)
    "w"   => 604800,   // seconds in a week   (7 days)
    "d"    => 86400,    // seconds in a day    (24 hours)
    "h"   => 3600,     // seconds in an hour  (60 minutes)
    "m" => 60,       // seconds in a minute (60 seconds)
    "s" => 1         // 1 second
    );
    $diff = abs($from - $to);
    $suffix = (($from > $to) ? ("from now") : ("ago"));
    foreach($units as $unit => $mult)
    if($diff >= $mult)
    {
        //$and = (($mult != 1) ? ("") : ("and "));
        $output .= "".$and.intval($diff / $mult)."".$unit.((intval($diff / $mult) == 1) ? ("") : (""));
        $diff -= intval($diff / $mult) * $mult;
    }
    $output .= " ".$suffix;
    $output = substr($output, strlen(""));
    if($output =='go' || $output ==' ago'){$output = 'A few secs ago';}
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend doing it in javascript.  You can use the [TimeAgo](http://timeago.yarp.com/) plugin for jquery.  The cool thing about this is it will update in realtime on the client side without any page refresh.  This is dead simple to use, and fits your requirements.