# Converting Date Format for Calculations in PHP

Tags: php, time

I'm displaying a due date for tasks in an m/d/y format. I'm displaying the day the task was posted in a "Posted X $name(s) ago" (eg. "Posted 6 day(s) ago").

I'm working on giving the timestamps (posted and due date) different CSS classes, depending on how many days there are from TODAY until the due date. (So the "Posted X" timestamp is less relevant, I just wanted to give a better picture.)

So far, I have the following down:

```
$cdate = $this->data['due'];
$today = time();
$dovi = date('m/d/Y', $today);
$difference = $cdate - $dovi;
$upcoming= floor($difference/60/60/24);
```

$cdate is pulling the due date from the DB, in m/d/y format. $today is telling us what today is (using the UNIX timestamp). $dovi is converting time() in to the m/d/y format. $difference is telling us the difference between today and the due date. $upcoming, in theory, should take that difference and dumb it down into a simple number.

I think that for the calculation to work, I would need to convert $cdate in to a UNIX timestamp or somehow convert both $today and $cdate into some other matching format other than m/d/y.

Does anyone have suggestions on the best way to make this work? I already have some code to run the CSS changes, the only thing I'm stuck on is this conversion/calculation issue to determine how many days from NOW (time()) the due date is. Thanks!!

Comment: Yes i had the same question before [function that formats the time difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343836/function-that-formats-the-time-difference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this? Assuming $this->data['due'] is in m/d/Y format.

```
$this->data['due'] = '7/28/2012';
$diff = strtotime($this->data['due']) - strtotime(date('m/d/Y'));
var_dump(date('d',$diff)); // 3
```

You can pass any valid parameter to php's date function to have it formatted however you would like.

Comment: I have strtotime($this->data['date_created'])) elsewhere in the code for a different purpose. I had assumed I couldn't define strtotime twice, but I'm going to try your code now. Thanks!

Comment: strtotime is just a php function that converts a textual timestamp into a unix timestamp http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: It's a step in the right direction! I changed date('d') to date('m/d'). I now have a list of NEW questions, but I think you answered what I posted. I'll save the other questions for a diff post if I can't figure them out myself. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php it allows you to format the diff (3 days) however you would like.

Answer (score 0):

Its long one, but works...

```
    $datetime = new DateTime("2012-07-22 02:03:50");   // your date in datetime type
    $curr_stamp = time();
    $act_stamp = mktime($datetime->format('H'), $datetime->format('i'), $datetime->format('s'), $datetime->format('n'), $datetime->format('j'), $datetime->format('Y'));

    $diff=$curr_stamp-$act_stamp;
    $day_diff = floor($diff / 86400);

    if($day_diff < 7)
        echo $day_diff." days ago";
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather elegant and right solution (and also viable after the end of **UNIX epoch**).

```
$today = new DateTime(); // creating `today` DateTime object
$expiry = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $this->data['due']) // creating DateTime object from already formatted date

$difference = $today->diff($expiry); // 1st variant to calculate difference between dates
$difference = date_diff($today, $expiry); // and 2nd variant

echo $difference->format('Interval (difference) is %R% days');
```

Remember that **UNIX epoch** (`timestamp`) will "end" "soon" and code based on timestamps possibly will face some problems (*maybe we will find the solution in future to avoid this, but ...*), it is better to use `DateTime` class, bec. even to calculate number of years for those who are born **before 1970** year can become kinda problem if you don't remember the date **1970.01.01** and trying to do it using timestamps (*it is widespread database practice BTW* :) ).

*Never do it (timestamps) for very old dates and look to the future and `DateTime` will SaveOurSouls.*