# Days passed since post returns '44 years ago'

Tags: php

I tried to find a solution but no luck. I have a $date in the format 2014-04-03 19:21:30
i tried to echo how many days have passed since that day using the function:

```
function timePassed($time){
        $time = time() - $time;
        $tokens = array (
            31536000 => 'year',
            2592000 => 'month',
            604800 => 'week',
            86400 => 'day',
            3600 => 'hour',
            60 => 'minute',
            1 => 'second'
        );

        foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
            if ($time < $unit) continue;
            $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
            return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
        }
    }
```

I get 44 years ago.. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: 44 years ago would be the Unix epoch, where `$time = 0`.

Comment: I had a similar question. You can get an answer there: [function that formats the time difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343836/function-that-formats-the-time-difference)

Comment: How are you passing the date `2014-04-03 19:21:30` into the timePassed function?

Comment: You should also have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: A month is 30 days for only 4 of 12 months, and a year is 365 days only 75% of the time. Use [`DateTime::diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).

Comment: You are correct but I won't need 100% accuracy. Just enough to  make sure the users have a rough idea of when it was posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the time elapsed using your logic and returns `1 week 5 days 21 hours 4 minutes 36 seconds`

Using strtotime(), I converted time to a number relative to 1/1/1970. You can now compare to time(). I also subtracted the amount of time elapsed in each step so it can continue to find the smaller increment.

This code will produce:

```
1 week
1 year
20 minutes 38 seconds
```

'

```
<?php
echo timePassed("2014-04-03 19:21:30") . "<br>";
echo timePassed("2013-02-03 19:21:30") . "<br>";
echo timePassed("2014-04-16 16:20:00") . "<br>";

function timePassed($time){
    $time = time() - strtotime($time);

    $tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    );

    $return = "";
    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
        if ($time < $unit) continue;
        $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        $time -= ($numberOfUnits * $unit);
        $return .= $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'') . " ";
        if ($unit > 60){
            // return if match greater than minutes
            return $return;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}

?>
```

To follow up on your last request, the following code should give you enough to modify it to your needs. This code will produce:

```
1 week
2013-02-03 19:21:30
23 hours
```

.

```
<?php
echo timePassed("2014-04-03 19:21:30") . "<br>";
echo timePassed("2013-02-03 19:21:30") . "<br>";
echo timePassed("2014-04-16 16:20:00") . "<br>";


function timePassed($time){
    $origtime = $time;
    $time = time() - strtotime($time);
    $tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    );
    $return = "";
    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
        if ($time < $unit) continue;
        $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        $time -= ($numberOfUnits * $unit);
        $return .= $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'') . " ";
        if ($unit > 60){
            // return if match greater than hours
            if ($unit > 2592000 ) {
                // if units greater than one month, show the original time
                return $origtime;
            }
            elseif ($unit == 2592000  && $numberOfUnits > 1){
                // if units is months, show the original time if more than one month
                return $origtime;
            }
            else {
                // units greater than minutes, show the time without further detail
                return $return;
            }
        }
    }
    return $return;
}

?>
```

Comment: You should point out the OP's bug, instead of just fixing their code.

Comment: is there a way to sort out the echo to do: If just posted: echo few seconds ago
if minutes ago: echo Xm Xs ago
if hous ago: echo X hours ago
if days ago: echo X days ago
if weeks: echo x weeks ago

Comment: The updated code will do what you wish. See the 3 examples included.

Comment: for the first echo, i get 1136289 1 week why is that? something to do with the time() i think but not sure

Comment: I accidentally left in a piece of debug code. I have removed `echo $time . "<br>";` If you remove this, it will remove the number before the `1 week`

Comment: yeah that fixed it. Last thing and I leave you alone i promise!! After a month, I want it to echo the date it was actually posted on rather than keep counting how many days passed. Would I need to replace 'month' to $date (which is in the format 2014-01-03 19:21:30) ?

Comment: I've added new code below the original answer showing how you could accomplish this variation - and it could be modified if I didn't fully understand you. Also, if you have found this answer helpful, I would appreciate your marking it correct. Thanks and glad I could help.

Comment: that you so much! this is what I wanted!